# Using ST_Difference to remove overlapping features?

Tags: postgis, sql, postgis-2.0, overlapping-features

I am trying to use ST_Difference to create a set of polygons (processing.trimmedparcelsnew) that do not contain any of the area covered by another set of polygons (test.single_geometry_1) using PostGis 2.1 (and Postgres SQL 9.3). Here is my query:

```
CREATE TABLE processing.trimmedparcelsnew AS
SELECT
    orig.id, ST_Difference(orig.geom, cont.geom) AS difference
FROM 
    test.single_geometry_1 cont,
    test.multi_geometry_1 orig;
```

But the resulting polygons have not been trimmed, instead they seem to have been split where they intersect with the other layer. I have tried just running the select without putting the result in a table and everything else I can think of, but I can't seem to get this function to work.

I have attached a picture of the result

[image]

---

After comments, I have tried adding a WHERE clause. I want the parcels that have no intersections, and the intersecting areas of the other parcels removed (the layer test.single_geometry represents contamination I want removed from my parcels). I tried an intersect but of course I actually want the non intersections so I am now trying a disjoint. I have also tried adding the orig to my table but the documentation for ST_Difference (http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Difference.html) does say it returns the exact geometry I need (a geometry that represents that part of geometry A that does not intersect with geometry B), so I am confused as to why I would want the original polygon in my table instead. Anyway, here is my modified code:

```
CREATE TABLE processing.trimmedparcelsnew AS
SELECT
    orig.id, ST_Difference(orig.geom, cont.geom) AS difference, orig.geom AS geom
FROM 
    test.single_geometry_1 cont,
    test.multi_geometry_1 orig
WHERE ST_Disjoint(orig.geom, cont.geom);
```

---

Following from dbaston's answer I have now tried:

```
CREATE TABLE processing.parcels_trimmed AS
SELECT id, COALESCE(ST_Difference(geom, (SELECT ST_Union(b.geom) 
                                         FROM test.single_geometry_1 b
                                         WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
                                         AND a.id != b.id)), a.geom)
FROM test.multi_geometry_1 a;
```

The result of this is just a copy of test.multi_geometry_1. Though now the splitting is no longer occurring.

I tried the earlier version, but again just get a copy of test.multi_geometry_1:

```
CREATE TABLE processing.parcels_trimmed_no_coalesce AS
SELECT id, COALESCE(ST_Difference(geom, (SELECT ST_Union(b.geom) 
                                         FROM test.single_geometry_1 b
                                         WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
                                         AND a.id != b.id)), a.geom)
FROM test.multi_geometry_1 a;
```

I am starting to wonder if there is something else I am doing wrong? The proceeding statement is:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS processing.parcels_trimmed_no_coalesce;
```

And I am running the queries from the PostgreSQL SQL query window and Openjump.

The statement I use to see the table is:

```
SELECT * FROM processing.parcels_trimmed_no_coalesce;
```

---

In the interest of simplification I have now reduced this query down to just:

```
SELECT id, COALESCE(ST_Difference(geom, (SELECT ST_Union(b.geom) 
                                         FROM test.geometriestocutagainst b
                                         WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
                                         AND a.id != b.id)), a.geom)
FROM test.geometriestocut a;
```

This still results in just the original polygons (test.geometriestocut) when the desired result is the original trimmed against test.geometriestocutagainst.

Comment: You did not specify a `WHERE` clause, so you may have polynomial expansion in the resulting table.  How many rows are in `trimmedparcelsnew` ?

Comment: If you only want the difference where they intersect, you could try adding WHERE ST_Intersects(orig.geom, cont.geom). Otherwise, the difference of two polygons that do not intersect, is the original polygon.

Comment: There are 24 rows in trimmed parcel new, I want the difference even when they do not intersect, so would I correct that I need to use orig.geom in the table rather than difference?

Comment: A disjoint test should produce polynomial expansion -- each feature in *cont* to appear once for every feature in *orig* that doesn't overlap, and the difference will **never** change an input geometry

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification, but I am still not sure then why the original code is not working. If ST_Difference(orig.geom, cont.geom) returns the geometries in a that do not intersect with b, than why does the table contain the split geometry's rather than the geometries in a that do not intersect b.

Comment: I'm trying to follow this but getting lost among all of the temporary tables and copies.  Can you reduce your input data set down to a size that will let your test your query interactively in OpenJUMP, without having to create tables of intermediate results?

Comment: Ok, we can forget about making the table, its not the issue anyway I will post up the part of the query that's giving the problem

Comment: Didn't realize that `geometriestocut` was not the same as `geometriestocutagainst`.  Wouldn't removing the `a.id != b.id` condition do it, then?

Comment: couldnt you just use a left join with the st_difference function?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A self-join allows you to operate on the relationship between *pairs* of two features.  But I don't think you're interested in pairs: for each feature, you want to operate on the relationship between that feature and *all other* features in your dataset.  You can accomplish this with a subquery expression:

```
CREATE TABLE parcels_trimmed AS
SELECT id, ST_Difference(geom, (SELECT ST_Union(b.geom) 
                                FROM parcels b
                                WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
                                  AND a.id != b.id))
FROM parcels a;
```

You might see something odd in the results, though.  Parcels that don't have any overlaps are being dropped entirely!  That's because the `ST_Union` aggregate on an empty recordset is going to be `NULL`, and `ST_Difference(geom, NULL)` is `NULL`.  To smooth this over, you need to wrap your `ST_Difference` call in a `COALESCE`:

```
CREATE TABLE parcels_trimmed AS
SELECT id, COALESCE(ST_Difference(geom, (SELECT ST_Union(b.geom) 
                                         FROM parcels b
                                         WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
                                         AND a.id != b.id)), a.geom)
FROM parcels a;
```

This means that if the result of `ST_Difference` is `NULL`, the coalesced expression will evaluate to the original geometry.

The above query will remove overlapping areas from your domain entirely.  If you instead want to pick a winner, you could do `a.id < b.id`, or some other criterion, instead of `a.id != b.id`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately I am having trouble getting this to work for me, instead just end up with the original polygon (a). I will edit my question with more info. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as you. I don't know if you already found a solution to your problem, but I modified the accepted answer above and I got what I wanted.

```
CREATE TABLE parcels_trimmed AS
SELECT id, COALESCE(ST_Difference(geom, (SELECT ST_Collect(b.geom) 
                                         FROM parcels b
                                         WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
                                         )), a.geom)
FROM parcels a;
```

Answer (score 2):

I use ST_DifferenceAgg() from [the PostGIS Addons](https://github.com/pedrogit/postgisaddons/blob/master/postgis_addons.sql). You have to merge the two tables together, have a unique identifier and an index on the geometry column. Here is a short example:

```
WITH overlappingtable AS (
  SELECT 1 id, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 1, 3 2, 3 0, 0 1), (1.5 1.333, 2 1.333, 2 0.666, 1.5 0.666, 1.5 1.333))') geom
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 id, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((1 1, 3.8 2, 4 0, 1 1))')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 id, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((2 1, 4.6 2, 5 0, 2 1))')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 id, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((3 1, 5.4 2, 6 0, 3 1))')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 id, ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((3 1, 5.4 2, 6 0, 3 1))')
)
SELECT a.id, ST_DifferenceAgg(a.geom, b.geom) geom
FROM overlappingtable a,
     overlappingtable b
WHERE a.id = b.id OR -- Make sure to pass at least once the polygon with itself
      ((ST_Contains(a.geom, b.geom) OR -- Select all the containing, contained and overlapping polygons
        ST_Contains(b.geom, a.geom) OR
        ST_Overlaps(a.geom, b.geom)) AND
       (ST_Area(a.geom) < ST_Area(b.geom) OR -- Make sure bigger polygons are removed from smaller ones
        (ST_Area(a.geom) = ST_Area(b.geom) AND -- If areas are equal, arbitrarily remove one from the other but in a determined order so it's not done twice.
         a.id < b.id)))
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING ST_Area(ST_DifferenceAgg(a.geom, b.geom)) > 0 AND NOT ST_IsEmpty(ST_DifferenceAgg(a.geom, b.geom));
```

This will merge the overlapping parts with the biggest overlapping polygon. If you want to keep the overlapping part separated look at the ST_splitAgg() example.